# For a huge txt.gz file, how could I decompress from line#n to line#m or one line each time. (python)

Tags: python, gzip

About a log file txt.gz which is too big(2-8 GB) to uzip it, I want to decompress it line by line on python, is there any way to do it? (like file.readline(0))
Currently using the gz.open, do not have enough memory.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] of what you attempted when you ran out of memory? Python's `gzip` does support chunk-by-chunk reading without loading the complete file into RAM.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Brian61354270 here is my uncompressed code 
with gzip.open(file_path,'rt') as f:
        line_content = f.readline()
        if not line_content:
                break
        line_reader(line_content)
the file is txt.gz the txt original is about 3 GB, the task manager gives me memory 99% occupancy